# Using a template inside a class

Tags: class

I'm trying to use a template function, but I get an error

```
home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: sketch/emptyCode.ino.cpp.o: in function `startIOTservices()':
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/HomePi/emptyCode/emptyCode.ino:37: undefined reference to `void myTest::funcOne<bool>(bool)'
/home/guy/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: sketch/emptyCode.ino.cpp.o: in function `setup':
/home/guy/Documents/git/Arduino/HomePi/emptyCode/emptyCode.ino:70: undefined reference to `void myTest::funcOne<bool>(bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

inside `.cpp` file:

```
myTest::myTest()
{
        Serial.println("start");
}

template <class T1> 
void myTest::funcOne(T1 arg)
{
        Serial.println(arg);
}
```

inside `.h` file:

```
class myTest
{
public:
    myTest();
    template <class T1> 
    void funcOne(T1 arg);
};
```

and calling it from `.ino` file:

`testA.funcOne(true);`

What am I doing wrong ?

*EDIT 1*:

complete .h .cpp files - which originaly belongs to `myJSON` library which are deleted in this snip

```
#ifndef myJSON_h
#define myJSON_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "FS.h"

#define DOC_SIZE 1000

class myJSON
{
};

class myTest
{
public:
    myTest();
    template <class T1> 
    void funcOne(T1 arg);
};

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "myJSON.h"
#include "FS.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define LOG_LENGTH 4

myJSON::myJSON(char *filename, bool useserial)
{
}
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

myTest::myTest()
{
        Serial.println("start");
}

// template <typename T1> 
void myTest::funcOne(T1 arg)
{
        Serial.println(arg);
}
```

Comment: put the template function definition in the .h file.

Comment: @Juraj when leaving the template defining inside `.h` file only I get :`error: variable or field 'funcOne' declared void
 void myTest::funcOne(T1 arg)`

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example. The error might be in the calling/using source.

Comment: @thebusybee Since it is only example -  I've put `myTest` class inside another `.cpp`  , and `.h`files I'm currently using. `funcOne` is called during `setup()` function

Comment: Would you mind to show us the commands to compile and link? Oh, and the source of this other module, please. You can enable verbose output of the build in the preferences.

Comment: @thebusybee what do you mean commands to complie and link ?

Comment: You might like to [edit] your question with the now-current code. Please don't remove the old code because comments refer to it.

Comment: @thebusybee, there is nothing to edit. it is simple to reproduce the problem. it is build with Arduino IDE.

Comment: @thebusybee see edit 1

Comment: @Juraj you are right - Arduino IDE 1.8.2

Comment: @Juraj The OP said "_when leaving the template defining inside .h file only I get :error..._" so the source is not up-to-date. Therefore I asked for current sources. And I still miss the main module which calls `funcOne()`, since the mentioned error presumambly points there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the template method definiton to .h or define it in class. it is not a real function, only a prescription for functions. Like this:

```
class myTest
{
public:
    myTest();
    template <class T1>
    void funcOne(T1 arg);
};

template <class T1>
void myTest::funcOne(T1 arg)
{
        Serial.println(arg);
}
```

or this

```
class myTest
{
public:
    myTest();
    template <class T1>
    void funcOne(T1 arg)
    {
            Serial.println(arg);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does it differ from what I originaly wrote in my question ?

Comment: the template is a declaration. the source where you use the template can't see it in cpp

Comment: Actually duplicate the function insde .h file ?

Comment: I write "move". It should be only in .h

Comment: Compilers don't know which class to use for the templated class if you compile the method separately. The common way is to put the method implementation into the header so the compiler is able to instantiate the specific implementation.

Comment: @thebusybee, there is `myTest::` to assign the method to class

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the @Guy.D the comment was addressed to.

Comment: @thebusybee, I know, but Guy has it right

Comment: @Guy.D, did it help?

Comment: @Juraj - tested now. YES! thank you very much